# How can a question marked as a favourite not appear in my list of favourites?

Tags: bug, bookmarks

I marked [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1512557/how-to-prove-there-exist-two-elements-in-a-positive-integer-sequence-with-bounde/3595703#3595703) as a favourite, and indeed the question shows a yellow star when I access it, but it doesn't appear in my list of favourites. How can this happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see it on your profile's favourites. Note that you can order the list by various criteria. Try ordering by "Added".

Comment: Thank you. That worked.